# What 90s show features a girl going through a portal in the woods and meeting a werewolf?

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing a show in the mid-to-late 90's. A girl goes through a portal in the woods and she has an adventure with a guy that is a werewolf.

At one point a witch puts a spell on her and hair grows freakishly long and they can only cut it off with an enchanted axe.

Does anyone have any idea what it was called?

Comment: Her _what_ grows freakishly long?

Comment: Also, I suggest you edit your title so that it becomes less generic and more search-friendly.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236949/fairy-tale-movie-series-where-a-villain-is-dispatched-with-a-poisoned-comb (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7):

the 10th kingdom is the closest thing I got however its not exact

[the 10th kingdom](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0207275/?ref_=sr_1)

her hair grows freakishly long

Comment: Seconded on the grounds that the guy she is traveling with is named "Wolf" and has a tail.  Also, there is an enchanted axe