# Fairy tale movie/series where a villain is dispatched with a poisoned comb

Tags: story-identification, movie, fairy-tales

I remember something I saw on TV years ago. I have no idea how to search this without giving a bunch of clues that I remember.

It was a fairy tale movie. It had a long duration - it was either a movie split in parts, or had a few episodes. My feeling, which could be not accurate at all, is something about 5 hours. Could be 10, but I don't think it would be less than 3.

The strongest clue that I have is that the final villain, which is a human female (a beautiful one), and probably a witch, is killed by being scratched by a, um, comb-like hair clasp with sharp teeth who have poison. Which, not very wisely, said lady was wearing on her hair. The finale, I think, was during a ballroom party held at her castle. Probably to celebrate the completion of some nefarious scheme.

I remember some few other things. The main protagonist was female, and I think it was the villain's daughter. I also remember a bathtub involved somehow: either the protagonist's mother tried to kill her in a bathtub when young, or the bathtub was the portal to the other, magical world.

I also remember some unclear (or clear but I was innocent back then) flirting between the protagonist and  a human-looking wolf...during the course of their approaching the castle.

It is all quite hazy, but I feel I remember the first clue, about the villain's death, pretty well.

Can you tell me what this is?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when was "years ago?". Do you have any idea what TV station it might have been on?  Was it in English?

Comment: The language (spoken) was English.  I might have seen this in, umm, between 2000 and 2005 maybe? I live in Greece, so add a few years backwards for country of origin. And no clue about station of transmission....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is [*The 10th Kingdom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_10th_Kingdom). It is a mini series, and wikipedia puts its run time at 6.5 to 7 hours, depending on the edits.

It somewhat follows the story of Snow White, with some other fairy tales mixed in.  The evil queen, who is eventually reveled to be the main character's mother, accidentally traveled into the land of fairy tales after having a mental breakdown and almost killed her daughter.  The evil queen sent Wolf, the human-looking wolf character, into our world to find the prince who ran away. There he meets the main character, and over the course of the mini series the two fall in love.

Comment: This sounds too accurate to not be true! Just give me a few hours to check this out!

Comment: See if this rings any bells: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zl0Q8XevKKI&t=6m20s

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you all!

Comment: This was my first thought. The female protagonist was almost drowned in the bath by her mother as a child, which is another matching point. https://10thkingdom.fandom.com/wiki/Virginia_Lewis

Comment: As a matter of possible interest, the [poisoned comb](https://www.pitt.edu/~dash/grimm053.html) is indeed part of the Snow White tale as related by the Brothers Grimm.